# Pthreads don't seem to be using more than one processor

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have an application that spawns multiple child processes, which then go on to spawn multiple threads.  I can control the number of processes and threads that are spawned.  The threads do a specific read/write operation to a NAS, and I record how long this takes.

What's odd is that the time it takes to perform the read/write operation is *longer* with multiple threads.  I read /proc/stat before starting the application and when finished, and got this (after some math):

```
cpu0: 1.0050% usrtime, 2.5126% systime, 95.4774% idle, 0.5025% softirq
cpu1: 0.0000% usrtime, 0.0000% systime, 100.0000% idle, 0.0000% softirq
```

I also checked sched_getaffinity, and both CPUs are enabled for the child processes.  Is there something that I must do, besides spawning multiple threads, to make use of the multiple cores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're hardly using your CPU at all.  Going out to Network Attached Storage, your bottleneck is most likely your network connection.  How much data are you pushing and how much bandwidth can your pipeline (and your NAS) tolerate?

Comment: Additionally, I would guess that the machine is using the other CPU 0% of the time because there is a cost involved in moving a process or thread between processors.  There's no point in paying that cost if there is no contention for the processor among the threads.

Comment: Just for this test I was sending two 1Mb files. The application spawned two threads, one for sending each file. We have ran the application on files as large as 2Gb, with the same results. I was hoping that by using smaller files, we were taking bandwidth problems out of the equation. I will check up on the stats on our NAS, and make sure we don't overload it in future tests. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hmm...interesting. Perhaps I am not dividing the work correctly among the threads then.

Comment: It wouldn't matter how you divide up the work.  If there's never a situation where two threads need to run at the same time (like when you are 1% utilized on one processor and your threads are taking turns waking up to fill a network buffer) the scheduler will never bother moving one of them to another processor.